# Strange behavior with reduce and fold on identical code block

Tags: scala, conditional-statements, ternary

**EDIT**
Ok, @dhg discovered that dot-method syntax required if the code block to fold() is not bound to a val (why with reduce() in the same code block one can use space-method syntax, I don't know). At any rate, the end result is the nicely concise:

```
result.map { row =>
  addLink( row.href, row.label )
}.fold(NodeSeq.Empty)(_++_)
```

Which negates to some degree the original question; i.e. in many cases one can higher-order away either/or scenarios and avoid "fat", repetitive if/else statements.

**ORIGINAL**
Trying to reduce if/else handling when working with possibly empty collections like List[T]

For example, let's say I need to grab the latest news articles to build up a *NodeSeq* of html news `<li><a>links</a></li>`:

```
val result = dao.getHeadlines // List[of model objects]
if(result.isEmpty) NodeSeq.Empty
else 
  result map { row =>
    addLink( row.href, row.label ) // NodeSeq
  } reduce(_ ++ _)
```

This is OK, pretty terse, but I find myself wanting to go ternary style to address these only-will-ever-be either/or cases:

```
result.isEmpty ? NodeSeq.Empty :
  result map { row =>
    addLink( row.href, row.label )
  } reduce(_ ++ _)
```

I've seen some old postings on pimping ternary onto boolean, but curious to know what the alternatives are, if any, to streamline if/else?

`match {...}` is, IMO, a bit bloated for this scenario, and `for {...} yield` doesn't seem to help much either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to check for emptiness at all.  Just use `fold` instead of `reduce` since `fold` allows you to specify a default "empty" value:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4).map(_ + 1).fold(0)(_+_)
res0: Int = 14

scala> List[Int]().map(_ + 1).fold(0)(_+_)
res1: Int = 0
```

Here's an example with a `List` of `Seq`s:

```
scala> List(1,2).map(Seq(_)).fold(Seq.empty)(_++_)
res14: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> List[Int]().map(Seq(_)).fold(Seq.empty)(_++_)
res15: Seq[Int] = List()
```

**EDIT**: Looks like the problem in your sample has to do with the dropping of dot (`.`) characters between methods.  If you keep them in, it all works:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).map(i => node).fold(NodeSeq.Empty)(_ ++ _)
res57: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<li><a href="/foo">Link</a></li>, <li><a href="/foo">Link</a></li>, <li><a href="/foo">Link</a></li>)
```

Comment: thus the question, on empty result got a stacktrace re: empty reduceLeft. Compiler does not like fold version of the reduce.

Comment: Note that `fold` and `reduce` have different signatures.  If you change `reduce` to `fold`, you need to add the default value argument.

Comment: May be the case, but it does not work with a List[NodeSeq], not with fold at any rate. Seems the type is lost, whereas with reduce NodeSeq is inferred. Not sure what the deal is.

Comment: can you post a complete example that compiles showing the failure?

Comment: if I store the collection to fold in a val, then it works to some degree; gives me a List[NodeSeq], but I'm looking for a NodeSeq in addition to reducing keystrokes not adding ;-) I guess if fold can work in the same manner that the reduce currently does, then the if/else/ternary question has been solved, as that would likely be the most concise way to deal with non-Option'd collections when trying to build NodeSeqs and the like

Comment: yeah, but then it doesn't, compiler then demands the type for row in "result map { row =>" (see original post), which it infers just fine (model.Article) with reduce (without the . method syntax) and with fold when I store contents in a val first. I agree that fold is the way to go here if it can handle the empty case, but only if it doesn't involve the extra typing that I'm trying to avoid in the first place (yes, the if/else is plenty concise, but when you have a hundred+ NodeSeq view snippets to build, less is more)

Comment: sorry, just +1'd you, tricky problem, one that doesn't appear to have an easy answer (otherwise I assume we'd be seeing several takes on the solution)

Comment: scrap that, you got it, ALL . method syntax required with fold (I missed the opening list.map)